# Parallel Merge Sort with threads /much/ slower than Seq. Merge Sort. Help

Tags: c, pthreads, parallel-processing, mutex, mergesort

http://pastebin.com/YMS4ehRj

^ This is my implementation of parallel merge sort. Basically what I do is, For every split, the first half is handled by a thread whereas the second half is sequential (i.e.) say we have an array of 9 elements, [0..4] is handled by Thread 1, [0..1] is handled Thread 2, [5..6] is handled by thread 3 (Look at the source code for clarification).

Everything else stays the same, like Merging. But the problem is, this runs much slower than merge sort, even slower than normal bubble sort! And I mean for an array of 25000 int's. I'm not sure where the bottleneck is: Is it the mutex locking? Is it the merging?

Any ideas on how to make this faster?

Comment: You shouldn't use a pastebin expiring in one day for stackoverflow questions—it prevents anyone else from learning how to solve your problem next week (or answer your question tomorrow).

Comment: You shouldn't use pastebins at all.

Comment: Don't implement a recursive-style mergeSort by just doing the same bits in parallel.  When the sub-lists get down to, say, 1000 long, the overhead of thread comms starts to approach the time taken for the merges, so just quicksort in place, (or whatever - just seen sth post - same point). Also, as others have said, just queue your mergers to [no. of cores] threads, or some other threadPool implementation.  You can synchronize the merges with callbacks.  If you do that, the 'tiled mergeSort' on a 4/8 core processor will sort 1000000 integers ~six times faster than a single-thread quicksort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a large number of threads, each of which then only does very little work. To sort 25000 ints you create about 12500 threads that spawn other threads and merge their results, and about 12500 threads that only sort *two* ints each.

The overhead from creating all those threads far outweighs the gains you get from parallel processing.

To avoid this, make sure that each thread has a reasonable amount of work to do. For example, if one thread finds that it only has to sort <10000 numbers it can simply sort them itself with a normal merge sort, instead of spawning new threads.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have a finite number of cores on your system, why would you want to create more threads than cores?

Also, it isn't clear why you need to have a mutex at all.  As far as I can tell from a quick scan, the program doesn't need to share the threads[lthreadcnt] outside the local function.  Just use a local variable and you should be golden.

Comment: Good point there. I was absorbed into this boxed thinking because I've been working on this for ~5 hours now. O.o

And you do make a point about creating humungous number of threads (~12500). So a serial split but a parallel merge would be faster?

Comment: Well you could do parallel split with a recursion limit (nice for 2 & 4 cores, not so nice for 6 or 8), but serial split would probably be much more efficient.  You also are not doing any I/O so large numbers of threads are not going to make anything more efficient.   This may go way beyond where you want to go, but if you can split the arrays on cache line boundaries you are likely to get a performance win there as well since contention is expensive.  With fewer threads looking at large amounts of data this is less important though.

Answer (score 1):

Your parallelism is too fine-grained, there are too many threads which are doing just small work. You can define a threshold so that arrays which have smaller sizes than the threshold are sequentially sorted. Be careful about the number of spawned threads, a good indication is that the number of threads are usually not much bigger than the number of cores.

Because much of your computation is in `merge` function, another suggestion is using **Divide-and-Conquer Merge** instead of simple merge. The advantage is two-fold: the running time is smaller and it is easy to spawn threads for running parallel merging. You can get the idea of how to implement parallel merge here: http://drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/229204454. They also have an article about Parallel Merge Sort which might be helpful for you: http://drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/229400239