# Pthreads unexplained segmentation fault

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads, mergesort

I implemented a parallel merge sort algorithm from Cormen's well-known text.  I wrote it in C using pthreads, and compiled with MinGW on Win7 x64 (also tested later with GCC in Ubuntu with same results).  My first approach at the parallelization was naïve... I spawned a new thread at every recursion level (which is actually what Cormen's pseudocode implies).  However this usually ends up either taking way too long or crashing due to segmentation fault (I can assume there is some hard limit to how many threads the system can handle).  This seems to be a common newbie mistake for recursive parallelization, in fact I found a similar [DISCUSSION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113331/parallel-merge-sort-with-threads-much-slower-than-seq-merge-sort-help) on this site.  So I instead used the recommendation in that thread, namely setting a threshold for problem size, and if the function that spawns new threads is given a set smaller than the threshold (say 10,000 elements) then it just operates on the elements directly, rather than creating a new thread for such a small set.

Now everything seemed to be working fine.  I tabulated some of my results below.  N is problem size (a set of integers [1, 2, 3, ..., N] thoroughly scrambled) and threshold is the value below which my parallel sort and parallel merge functions refuse to spawn new threads.  The first table shows sort time in ms, the second shows how many sort/merge worker threads were spawned in each case.  Looking at the N=1E6 and N=1E7 rows in the bottom table, you can see that anytime I lower the threshold such that more than ~8000 merge workers are allowed, I get segmentation fault.  Again, I assume that is due to some limit the system gives on threads, and I'd be happy to hear more about that, but it's not my main question.

The main question, is why does the final row get segfault when trying to use a fairly high threshold, which would have spawned an expected 15/33 worker threads (following pattern from previous rows).  Surely this is not too many threads for my system to handle.  The one instance which did complete (lower right cell in table) used about 1.2GB RAM (my system has 6GB), and the threaded versions never seem to take more RAM compared to the ones with 0 threads at the right of each row.

- I don't think I am hitting any sort of heap limit... tons of RAM available and it should only take ~1GB even if it was allowed to spawn the 15/33 threads.
- I also don't think it is a stack problem.  I designed the program to use minimal stack, and I don't think the footprint each thread would be related to problem size N at all, only the heap.  I'm pretty inexperienced with this... but I did a core dump stack backtrace in gdb and the addresses from top to bottom of stack seem close enough to rule out overflow there.
- I tried reading the return values of pthread_create... in Windows I got a value of 11 a few times before the crash (but it didn't seem to trigger the crash, since there were a few 11's, then a few 0's, i.e. no error, then another 11).  That error code is EAGAIN, resources unavailable... but I am not sure what it really means here.  Moreover, in Ubuntu the error code was 0 every time even right up to the crash.
- I tried Valgrind and got a lot of messages about memory leaks, but I am not sure those are legit since I know Valgrind requires extra resources, and I was able to get those types of errors on other problem set sizes that worked fine without Valgrind.

It's pretty obvious it's related to problem size and system resources... I'm hoping there's some piece of general knowledge I'm missing that makes the answer really clear.

Any ideas?  Sorry for the long wall of text... thanks if you've read this far!  I can post the source if it seems relevant.

[image]

EDIT: Source added for reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

const int               N = 100000000;
const int  SORT_THRESHOLD = 10000000;
const int MERGE_THRESHOLD = 10000000;

int  sort_thread_count = 0;
int merge_thread_count = 0;

typedef struct s_pmergesort_args {
    int *vals_in, p, r, *vals_out, s;
} pmergesort_args;

typedef struct s_pmerge_args {
    int *temp, p1, r1, p2, r2, *vals_out, p3;
} pmerge_args;

void *p_merge_sort(void *v_pmsa);
void *p_merge(void *v_pma);
int binary_search(int val, int *temp, int p, int r);

int main() {
    int *values, i, rand1, rand2, temp, *sorted;
    long long rand1a, rand1b, rand2a, rand2b;
    struct timeval start, end;

    /* allocate values on heap and initialize */
    values = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    sorted = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        values[i] = i + 1;
        sorted[i] = 0;
    }

    /* scramble
     *  - complicated logic to maximize swapping
     *  - lots of testing (not shown) was done to verify optimal swapping */
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < N/10; i++) {
        rand1a = (long long)(N*((double)rand()/(1+(double)RAND_MAX)));
        rand1b = (long long)(N*((double)rand()/(1+(double)RAND_MAX)));
        rand1 = (int)((rand1a * rand1b + rand()) % N);
        rand2a = (long long)(N*((double)rand()/(1+(double)RAND_MAX)));
        rand2b = (long long)(N*((double)rand()/(1+(double)RAND_MAX)));
        rand2 = (int)((rand2a * rand2b + rand()) % N);
        temp = values[rand1];
        values[rand1] = values[rand2];
        values[rand2] = temp;
    }

    /* set up args for p_merge_sort */
    pmergesort_args pmsa;
    pmsa.vals_in = values;
    pmsa.p = 0;
    pmsa.r = N-1;
    pmsa.vals_out = sorted;
    pmsa.s = 0;

    /* sort */
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    p_merge_sort(&pmsa);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    /* verify sorting */
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        if (sorted[i] < sorted[i-1]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: array is not sorted.\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    printf("Success: array is sorted.\n");
    printf("Sorting took %dms.\n", (int)(((end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec))/1000));

    free(values);
    free(sorted);

    printf("(  sort threads created: %d )\n", sort_thread_count);
    printf("( merge threads created: %d )\n", merge_thread_count);

    return 0;
}

void *p_merge_sort(void *v_pmsa) {
    pmergesort_args pmsa = *((pmergesort_args *) v_pmsa);
    int *vals_in = pmsa.vals_in;
    int p = pmsa.p;
    int r = pmsa.r;
    int *vals_out = pmsa.vals_out;
    int s = pmsa.s;

    int n = r - p + 1;
    pthread_t worker;

    if (n > SORT_THRESHOLD) {
        sort_thread_count++;
    }

    if (n == 1) {
        vals_out[s] = vals_in[p];
    } else {
        int *temp = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        int q = (p + r) / 2;
        int q_ = q - p + 1;

        pmergesort_args pmsa_l;
        pmsa_l.vals_in = vals_in;
        pmsa_l.p = p;
        pmsa_l.r = q;
        pmsa_l.vals_out = temp;
        pmsa_l.s = 0;

        pmergesort_args pmsa_r;
        pmsa_r.vals_in = vals_in;
        pmsa_r.p = q+1;
        pmsa_r.r = r;
        pmsa_r.vals_out = temp;
        pmsa_r.s = q_;

        if (n > SORT_THRESHOLD) {
            pthread_create(&worker, NULL, p_merge_sort, &pmsa_l);
        } else {
            p_merge_sort(&pmsa_l);
        }
        p_merge_sort(&pmsa_r);

        if (n > SORT_THRESHOLD) {
            pthread_join(worker, NULL);
        }

        pmerge_args pma;
        pma.temp = temp;
        pma.p1 = 0;
        pma.r1 = q_ - 1;
        pma.p2 = q_;
        pma.r2 = n - 1;
        pma.vals_out = vals_out;
        pma.p3 = s;
        p_merge(&pma);
        free(temp);
    }
}

void *p_merge(void *v_pma) {
    pmerge_args pma = *((pmerge_args *) v_pma);
    int *temp = pma.temp;
    int p1 = pma.p1;
    int r1 = pma.r1;
    int p2 = pma.p2;
    int r2 = pma.r2;
    int *vals_out = pma.vals_out;
    int p3 = pma.p3;

    int n1 = r1 - p1 + 1;
    int n2 = r2 - p2 + 1;
    int q1, q2, q3, t;
    pthread_t worker;

    if (n1 < n2) {
        t = p1; p1 = p2; p2 = t;
        t = r1; r1 = r2; r2 = t;
        t = n1; n1 = n2; n2 = t;
    }
    if (n1 > MERGE_THRESHOLD) {
        merge_thread_count++;
    }

    if (n1 == 0) {
        return;
    } else {

        q1 = (p1 + r1) / 2;
        q2 = binary_search(temp[q1], temp, p2, r2);
        q3 = p3 + (q1 - p1) + (q2 - p2);
        vals_out[q3] = temp[q1];

        pmerge_args pma_l;
        pma_l.temp = temp;
        pma_l.p1 = p1;
        pma_l.r1 = q1-1;
        pma_l.p2 = p2;
        pma_l.r2 = q2-1;
        pma_l.vals_out = vals_out;
        pma_l.p3 = p3;

        if (n1 > MERGE_THRESHOLD) {
            pthread_create(&worker, NULL, p_merge, &pma_l);
        } else {        
            p_merge(&pma_l);
        }        

        pmerge_args pma_r;
        pma_r.temp = temp;
        pma_r.p1 = q1+1;
        pma_r.r1 = r1;
        pma_r.p2 = q2;
        pma_r.r2 = r2;
        pma_r.vals_out = vals_out;
        pma_r.p3 = q3+1;

        p_merge(&pma_r);

        if (n1 > MERGE_THRESHOLD) {
            pthread_join(worker, NULL);
        }
    }
}

int binary_search(int val, int *temp, int p, int r) {
    int low = p;
    int mid;
    int high = (p > r+1)? p : r+1;

    while (low < high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (val <= temp[mid]) {
            high = mid;
        } else {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return high;
}
```

EDIT 2: Added new image below showing "max" and "total" RAM used by each version (max meaning highest simultaneous allocation/usage and total meaning the sum of all allocation requests through the program's life).  These suggest that with N=1E8 and threshold=1E7 I should get a max usage of 3.2GB (which my system should be able to support).  But again... I guess it is related to some other limitation in the pthread library... not my actual system resources.

[image]

Comment: I don't think your problem is specific enough for you to get useful answers.  A minimal code example would help.

Comment: @VaughnCato Ok, thanks for the suggestion.  I added the source.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Did you run the program in the debugger to see which line it usually crashes at?

Comment: Looks like it is running out of memory.  I get malloc returning null around line 105.

Comment: @user315052 Yes, it gets SIGSEGV at line 177 `vals_out[q3] = temp[q1];` when N = 1E8 and THRESHOLD <= 1E7 (there are some values of THRESHOLD above 1E7 for which it works and spawns very small number of new threads and runs successfully).

Comment: @VaughnCato That doesn't seem right.  Try increasing the two THRESHOLD constants near the beginning to equal N (it should then run serially) and see if you get same result.  I can run it fine like that... it uses 1.2GB of heap but it works.

Comment: Because memory is being allocated and freed, perhaps when it is threaded you have more memory allocated all at once than when it is running serially.

Comment: @VaughnCato I considered that possibility myself, but I don't think it is the case.  For instance, if N is 1E7 and threshold is 1E7 (serial run) it uses around 130MB.  If N is 1E7 and threshold is 1E4 (parallel run with over 8000 threads used), it uses around 140MB.  So even with thousands of threads it barely uses any more memory.  Just eyeballing process manager on my system when the one in question crashes, it is using under 1GB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is running out of memory.  In your example, if the code is run sequentially, then the most memory it has allocated at one time is 1.6GB.  When using threads, it is using more than 3GB.  I put some wrappers around the malloc/free functions, and got this result:

```
Allocation of 12500000 bytes failed with 3074995884 bytes already allocated.
```

It's easy to see that the memory usage would be more when threaded.  In that case, it would be simultaneously sorting both the left and right sides of the overall array, and allocating two large temp buffers to do it.  When run sequentially, the temp buffer for the left half would be freed before sorting the right half.

Here are the wrappers I used:

```
static size_t total_allocated = 0;
static size_t max_allocated = 0;
static pthread_mutex_t total_allocated_mutex;

static void *allocate(int n)
{
  void *result = 0;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&total_allocated_mutex);
  result = malloc(n);
  if (!result) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Allocation of %d bytes failed with %u bytes already allocated\n",n,total_allocated);
  }
  assert(result);
  total_allocated += n;
  if (total_allocated>max_allocated) {
    max_allocated = total_allocated;
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&total_allocated_mutex);
  return result;
}


static void *deallocate(void *p,int n)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&total_allocated_mutex);
  total_allocated -= n;
  free(p);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&total_allocated_mutex);
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I guess that should have been more obvious. :-/  I guess I was so hung up on the call to `free()` coming after the left and right sort calls BOTH completed (or sync'ed) that I overlooked the fact that each of those calls could potentially make a `malloc()` and `free()` on its own.  Can you explain more about how you used wrappers to get those results?  Sounds like a skill I should have.  Thanks!

Comment: And I guess my cheapskate method of watching the Windows task manager RAM usage is not very reliable then?  Because it still shows me less than 1GB used when the threaded version crashes.  I did notice that the core dump file in Linux was 3.2GB.  Any more reliable way to watch RAM usage real time?

Comment: @The111: I posted my wrappers.  Under Linux, using top and watching the virtual memory size seems to be pretty accurate, but when running threaded, it fails so fast that it isn't very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the wrappers Vaughn, they are awesome.  You've helped me understand some things about this algorithm I definitely had wrong.  BUT... I still think I am getting SIGSEGV long before resources are expended.  See update image in OP.  Note that I am using "max allocated" to mean what you meant by "total allocated" in your wrapper (in my wrapper, total means aggregate total as explained in OP edit).  Other interesting point: try running with N=1E7 and threshold=1E4.  Result?  SIGSEGV and your wrapper gives: `Allocation of 1250000 bytes failed with 471031628 bytes already allocated`

Comment: @The111: I suspect this is a result of severe memory fragmentation.  The order of allocations and deallocations is going to be very irregular in the threaded version, causing lots of holes in the allocated memory.  This makes it difficult to find large chunks of contiguous memory to allocate.

Comment: Thanks again Vaughn, that sounds like a pretty reasonable assumption, especially since these chunks range in size quite a bit, some of them being huge.  I'm not sure how we'd prove it, short of a really painful diagram to draw... but I think you might have the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I ran it and got:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 7120.0x14dc]
0x004017df in p_merge (v_pma=0x7882c120) at t.c:177
177             vals_out[q3] = temp[q1];
(gdb) p q3
$1 = 58
(gdb) p vals_out
$2 = (int *) 0x0
(gdb)
```

This is a NULL pointer dereference. I would put an assertion after you allocate `temp` to make sure allocation succeeded.

```
    int *temp = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    assert(temp);
```

Analyzing your algorithm a bit, it seems you are pre-allocating the memory you need to do the merge as you recursively go down. You might want to consider altering your algorithm to do the allocation at the time you actually perform the merge.

But, if I recall correctly, merge sort allocates the second array at the very top of the algorithm before any merging occurs, then as the recursive calls unwind, they flip back and forth between the two arrays as the merge runs get longer. This way, there is only one `malloc` call ever in the whole algorithm. In addition to using less memory, it will perform much better.

My SWAG at modifying your code to use a single allocated temporary array allocated at the top of the algorithm is shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

const int               N = 100000000;
const int  SORT_THRESHOLD = 10000000;
const int MERGE_THRESHOLD = 10000000;

int  sort_thread_count = 0;
int merge_thread_count = 0;

typedef struct s_pmergesort_args {
    int *vals_in, p, r, *vals_out, s, *temp;
} pmergesort_args;

typedef struct s_pmerge_args {
    int *temp, p1, r1, p2, r2, *vals_out, p3;
} pmerge_args;

void *p_merge_sort(void *v_pmsa);
void *p_merge(void *v_pma);
int binary_search(int val, int *temp, int p, int r);

int main() {
    int *values, i, rand1, rand2, temp, *sorted, *scratch;
    long long rand1a, rand1b, rand2a, rand2b;
    struct timeval start, end;

    /* allocate values on heap and initialize */
    values = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    sorted = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    scratch = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        values[i] = i + 1;
        sorted[i] = 0;
    }

    /* scramble
     *  - complicated logic to maximize swapping
     *  - lots of testing (not shown) was done to verify optimal swapping */
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < N/10; i++) {
        rand1a = (long long)(N*((double)rand()/(1+(double)RAND_MAX)));
        rand1b = (long long)(N*((double)rand()/(1+(double)RAND_MAX)));
        rand1 = (int)((rand1a * rand1b + rand()) % N);
        rand2a = (long long)(N*((double)rand()/(1+(double)RAND_MAX)));
        rand2b = (long long)(N*((double)rand()/(1+(double)RAND_MAX)));
        rand2 = (int)((rand2a * rand2b + rand()) % N);
        temp = values[rand1];
        values[rand1] = values[rand2];
        values[rand2] = temp;
    }

    /* set up args for p_merge_sort */
    pmergesort_args pmsa;
    pmsa.vals_in = values;
    pmsa.p = 0;
    pmsa.r = N-1;
    pmsa.vals_out = sorted;
    pmsa.s = 0;
    pmsa.temp = scratch;

    /* sort */
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    p_merge_sort(&pmsa);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    /* verify sorting */
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        if (sorted[i] < sorted[i-1]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: array is not sorted.\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    printf("Success: array is sorted.\n");
    printf("Sorting took %dms.\n", (int)(((end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec))/1000));

    free(values);
    free(sorted);
    free(scratch);

    printf("(  sort threads created: %d )\n", sort_thread_count);
    printf("( merge threads created: %d )\n", merge_thread_count);

    return 0;
}

void *p_merge_sort(void *v_pmsa) {
    pmergesort_args pmsa = *((pmergesort_args *) v_pmsa);
    int *vals_in = pmsa.vals_in;
    int p = pmsa.p;
    int r = pmsa.r;
    int *vals_out = pmsa.vals_out;
    int s = pmsa.s;
    int *scratch = pmsa.temp;

    int n = r - p + 1;
    pthread_t worker;

    if (n > SORT_THRESHOLD) {
        sort_thread_count++;
    }

    if (n == 1) {
        vals_out[s] = vals_in[p];
    } else {
        int q = (p + r) / 2;
        int q_ = q - p + 1;

        pmergesort_args pmsa_l;
        pmsa_l.vals_in = vals_in;
        pmsa_l.p = p;
        pmsa_l.r = q;
        pmsa_l.vals_out = scratch;
        pmsa_l.s = p;
        pmsa_l.temp = vals_out;

        pmergesort_args pmsa_r;
        pmsa_r.vals_in = vals_in;
        pmsa_r.p = q+1;
        pmsa_r.r = r;
        pmsa_r.vals_out = scratch;
        pmsa_r.s = q+1;
        pmsa_r.temp = vals_out;

        if (n > SORT_THRESHOLD) {
            pthread_create(&worker, NULL, p_merge_sort, &pmsa_l);
        } else {
            p_merge_sort(&pmsa_l);
        }
        p_merge_sort(&pmsa_r);

        if (n > SORT_THRESHOLD) {
            pthread_join(worker, NULL);
        }

        pmerge_args pma;
        pma.temp = scratch + p;
        pma.p1 = 0;
        pma.r1 = q_ - 1;
        pma.p2 = q_;
        pma.r2 = n - 1;
        pma.vals_out = vals_out + p;
        pma.p3 = s - p;
        p_merge(&pma);
    }
}

void *p_merge(void *v_pma) {
    pmerge_args pma = *((pmerge_args *) v_pma);
    int *temp = pma.temp;
    int p1 = pma.p1;
    int r1 = pma.r1;
    int p2 = pma.p2;
    int r2 = pma.r2;
    int *vals_out = pma.vals_out;
    int p3 = pma.p3;

    int n1 = r1 - p1 + 1;
    int n2 = r2 - p2 + 1;
    int q1, q2, q3, t;
    pthread_t worker;

    if (n1 < n2) {
        t = p1; p1 = p2; p2 = t;
        t = r1; r1 = r2; r2 = t;
        t = n1; n1 = n2; n2 = t;
    }
    if (n1 > MERGE_THRESHOLD) {
        merge_thread_count++;
    }

    if (n1 == 0) {
        return;
    } else {

        q1 = (p1 + r1) / 2;
        q2 = binary_search(temp[q1], temp, p2, r2);
        q3 = p3 + (q1 - p1) + (q2 - p2);
        vals_out[q3] = temp[q1];

        pmerge_args pma_l;
        pma_l.temp = temp;
        pma_l.p1 = p1;
        pma_l.r1 = q1-1;
        pma_l.p2 = p2;
        pma_l.r2 = q2-1;
        pma_l.vals_out = vals_out;
        pma_l.p3 = p3;

        if (n1 > MERGE_THRESHOLD) {
            pthread_create(&worker, NULL, p_merge, &pma_l);
        } else {
            p_merge(&pma_l);
        }

        pmerge_args pma_r;
        pma_r.temp = temp;
        pma_r.p1 = q1+1;
        pma_r.r1 = r1;
        pma_r.p2 = q2;
        pma_r.r2 = r2;
        pma_r.vals_out = vals_out;
        pma_r.p3 = q3+1;

        p_merge(&pma_r);

        if (n1 > MERGE_THRESHOLD) {
            pthread_join(worker, NULL);
        }
    }
}

int binary_search(int val, int *temp, int p, int r) {
    int low = p;
    int mid;
    int high = (p > r+1)? p : r+1;

    while (low < high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (val <= temp[mid]) {
            high = mid;
        } else {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return high;
}
```

Comment: That looks like about what I've been seeing, but I don't understand what is causing the SIGSEGV.

Comment: Thanks.  The assert fails if N is 1E8 and threshold is 1E7.  The puts us one tiny step closer to solving this... but it still doesn't explain it, unless you see something else I don't?

Comment: I am not an algorithmic genius, but there is a reason for Cormen's reputation, and I implemented his pseudocode as directly as possible.  Regarding memory usage, consider this.  In my "problem version" I am sorting 100,000,000 ints.  This is 400MB.  My output also requires 400MB.  Add in 400MB for temporary usage (whether all at once or piecemeal) and you get 3 x 400MB = 1.2GB, which unsurprisingly is exactly what this program costs on my machine when run in serial mode.  Parallel mode should not cost any more, as illustrated if you try with N=1E7 and threshold=1E3 and watch your RAM.

Comment: Although your ideas about where to call malloc do make sense and given the new post above maybe re-designing the algorithm would indeed help. :-)

Comment: @The111: So, I gave a whack at it. I don't really recognize this formulation of merge sort, so I will have to study it more. But, [these diffs](http://pastebin.com/k3kaHC3e) seem to work.

Comment: @The111: I hope you didn't get the impression I was slighting you in anyway. I was just making a recommendation based on what I was observing. Vaughn Cato's insights were very enlightening as well, that at each recursion depth of the parallel merge, the memory for the entire array was being allocated. So at depth 20, it would be 20 * 400MB == 8GB.

Comment: No, I didn't get that impression, and I hope my comment about Cormen likewise did not sound jerkish.  I am going to give your suggestions a look in a minute.  Been working on something else based on Cato's answers, and finding still a bit of a mystery here... editing OP in a sec.  Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: After your previous suggestion about moving the allocation closer to its usage, I spent a good deal of time analyzing the algorithm in Cormen's book.  It is indeed QUITE different from standard mergesort (which is challenging to parallelize), and the way he presents it I don't see it being possible to move the allocation and still have it work as he intended.  Wrapping my brain around his algorithm took the better part of several hours, and as it is late and that brain is fried, rather than try to understand all your diffs, I just pasted them one by one and then ran the program... continued

Comment: ... with the exception of the last diff where you deleted a free (not sure why?).  Anyway, the code did work, but it used slightly more memory in every case for me, whether serial or parallel.  See my new table with "max/total" values... for every single one with your version max and total were both slightly higher.  And the N=1E8 version would no longer run at all, even serially.  If I'm wrong and I pasted your diffs wrong, please link me to the entire code.  Thanks for your attempts though.  (by the way, I think the reason Cormen allocates early is because his sort base case requires it)

Comment: @The111: You need to remove that call to `free`. Complete program [here](http://pastebin.com/KexpR5HD).

Comment: Fantastic.  So much for Cormen's method. ;-)  Yours uses exactly the same amount of memory regardless of how many threads are spawned, and it uses less than his overall too, and runs faster.  N=1E8 now takes 1200MB RAM serial OR parallel, which is of course the aggregate total of allocations too.  Gonna take some time to wrap my head around all your changes.  I still have to give Cato the accept since I think his answer (memory fragmentation) more directly answers my original question... but your answers are equally appreciated and you have undoubtedly improved the algorithm!  Thanks!

Comment: Spent some more time this morning analyzing your algorithm.  Had to actually sketch out a simple run through it with problem size 10, but finally got to the bottom of it.  Very ingenious how you flip-flop back and forth between the `scratch` and `out` arrays for intermediate results of each merge.  And of course it unwinds to the correct `out` array because that is where the recursion started.  Simple once I got it, but also very elegant and very deep!  Once again, thanks!  Would upvote you again if I could!

Comment: One last quick note: the original version, when multi-threaded with ~50 threads (threshold = N/10) on 4-core system (i7 with HT disabled) gets max speedup of 2, efficiency of 50%.  Your optimized version gets speedup of 3.8, efficiency of 95% in same conditions.  So not just a memory saver, also better in terms of parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

Your stressing your system way too much, as a parallelization for speedup your implementation makes not much sense. Parallelization incurs a cost, your system as a whole has to do a lot of work when you flood it with threads like that, threads are not for free.

In particular for your "problem" that your program crashes if you ask for too much threads, this is entirely your fault: read the manual page for `pthread_create`. It states that that function returns a value, and it does it for a reason.

To gain speedup (which is what I suppose you are looking for) you can't expect to obtain more than you have physical cores in your system. Sometimes it is good to have a bit more threads (say twice as much) than cores, but soon the overhead that the threads create are far more than you can gain.

Then mergesort is an algorithm that typically is bound by the access to the RAM, not by the comparisons. RAM access (even when doing it streaming like in mergesort) is orders of magnitudes slower than the CPU. In addition your memory bus is not a parallel device, the only parallelism that you have in memory access are the caches (if they are). Blowing up your memory footprint by a factor of two, may kill all performance gains. In your code you even make it worse by allocating the memory down below in the individual thread invocations, since allocating memory by itself has a cost, the system has to coordinate these allocations.

To give it another start, first write a recursive mergesort algorithm that has a decent memory handling and access pattern. Only allocate some large buffers in the top node of the recursion and hand parts of it down to the recursive calls.

Create a separate merging routine that merges two sorted buffers into a third. Benchmark it, compute the micro-seconds per sort item that your algorithms spends. From that with the speed of your CPU compute the number cycles that you waste per sorted item. Read the assembler that your compiler produces for the merge and if you find that it looks too complicated, try to find out how to improve it.

After that, start adding parallelism to your recursive function.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I'm simply implementing an algorithm from a famous author of textbooks on algorithms... Thomas Cormen.  I understand we don't want way more threads than cores, but in this case we do need SOME more because of the unknown nature of the algorithm's course.  Note that with ~50 threads being spawned on a 4-core system, it has speedup of 3.5, efficiency 0.9.  With ~750 threads on 4-core system, it has speedup of 3.2, efficiency 0.8.  I don't think that is too shabby. ;-)  Thanks for the insights though, if I had time I'd love to dig through some assembly.