# Fastest Multithreading Sorting Method

Tags: c, multithreading, sorting, time, mergesort

Currently, I am creating a multi-threaded sorter that reads in a bunch of CSV files and outputs a single large sorted CSV file consisting of all the data in the CSV files. Right now, I am planning on sorting each of the CSV's in their individual thread using mergesort and then sorting it one last time when all the data from the threads are concatenated together. I am just curious whether only using mergesort would be considered "fast". After the threads concatenate the sorted data together, the data is sorted in their individual sections but overall, it is still unsorted.

Comment: You should read about [adaptive sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_sort).

Comment: I don't know about fastest, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11380649/315052) is an implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I thought that merge sort would be memory bound due to relatively tight loops in the merge function until I made a multi-threaded bottom up merge sort. With 4 threads, it was about 3 times as fast as a single-threaded merge sort. In this example, the array is split up into 4 parts, each part is merge-sorted, then thread 0 merges quarter arrays 0 and 1, and thread 2 merges quarter arrays 2 and 3, then thread 0 merges the two half arrays.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148025/multithreaded-bottom-up-merge-sort

gnu sort, which is a text file sort, does a multi-threaded merge sort on an array of pointers in the first pass used to create the initial temporary files (assuming the original file is larger than available memory). After the initial pass, it does a single threaded 16 way merge on the temporary files, since the bottleneck there is the disk I/O speed, not processor speed.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. I was planning on concatenating the individually sorted arrays and mergesorting again but that is just wasting time because they are essentially on the last step of mergesorting, which is the merge part. Now I am just thinking on whether I should use a linked list or just another array to hold together all of the individual struct arrays of the files.

Comment: @codemonkey - You could use an array of pointers to the structures instead of using a linked list.

Answer (score 1):

How large is your data? Sorting is `O(n log n)`, and the final merge step which is inherently not parallelizable is of course `O(n)`, so unless `log n` is utterly gigantic or the cost of comparisons is disproportionately large compared to the cost of moving data around, there's very little to be gained by multithreaded sorting.

If you still do want to try it, what's wrong with your approach is doing a final merge sort of the concatenated list. That's essentially going to be the same speed as doing the whole sort all over again. Instead, you want to merge the output from each pair of threads using a single merge operation rather than a whole merge-sort. Repeat this, halving the number of sorted lists you have each time, until the last step just merges 2 lists. You can break this work up into threads by setting up a hierarchical relationship between threads where, when two "sibling" threads in the hierarchy finish their jobs, one exits and the other "moves up" in the hierarchy and picks up merging its sibling's output.

Comment: I don't agree with the argument in your first paragraph. Each pass in a merge-sort takes roughly the same amount of time (because earlier passes have to do more merges whereas later passes have to do merges on larger lists), so even if `log n` is relatively low -- say, around 25 (meaning about 34M items) -- parallelizing early passes can have quite a large effect on the total time.

Comment: Each file has 28 columns and around 5000 lines. The amount of files can range from 1 - 1024.

Comment: You could sort 50000 lines (10x that many) in less time than it takes a thread to start. Multithreaded sorting is not even remotely going to make sense unless you have billions of lines.

Comment: 5,000 * 1024 is around the max amount of lines there can be, which is 5,120,000 lines.

Comment: Oh, I misread that as 5000 lines total. Still, even 5M lines is sufficiently small that it's unlikely to help. log is about 22.

Comment: This is a project for one of my classes so we have to use multi threading unfortunately. I would think multithreading would speed up the process overall if I am going through a directory and creating a new thread for every CSV file I see so that the sorting can begin while I am still searching for CSV files in the directory. Does a thread really take that much time to start?

Comment: A better question than "does a thread really take that much time to start?" is "does it really take that little time to sort thousands of objects?" and the answer is yes!